# Выполнение задач в определённое время на компьютере hh:mm

Tags: java

Допустим есть список часов с минутами: `[15.15, 18.30, 00.45]` и т.д.
Нужно выполнять некоторый Runnable в java приложении тогда, когда "на часах" будет
один из временных промежутков из списка выше. Как лучше реализовать подобное? Желательно без использования сторонних библиотек.

Я попытался сделать это так:
[image: Жалкая попытка]

Но оно не работает.

Comment: Создать таймер с интервалом срабатывания 1 минута и проверять настало ли время.

Comment: Я добавил попытку, можете глянуть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я пользуюсь нормальной библиотекой `java.time`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now().plusMinutes(1);

        Timer timer = new Timer();

        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("run");
                timer.cancel();
            }
        }, Date.from(ldt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()));
    }
```

Comment: Хотя и через календарь тоже должно работать...

Comment: Вопрос, почему после выполнения "run" приложение не завершает работу?

Comment: Потому что таймер в потоке, а его никто не завершал.

Comment: я добавил cancel после "run".sout но ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Где именно? Покажите

Comment: Используйте  Quartz и будет Вам счастье.

Comment: Всё, вопрос решён. Я просто вызывал cancel() в "run" для Task, а надо было timer.cancel();